# Google Compute Load Balancer

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 VM's using an ephemeral IP and one Static IP i have linked to my loadbalancer, the network firewall is allowing all the correct ports, and i've added my VM's to the correct pool, but the network load balancer doesn't seem to be routing requests. I can connect directly to the VM's fine using their ephemeral IP's but when i go to the load balancer IP it just hangs.

And help would be great, i've recreated the load balancer many times and checked the pool settings and forward settings about ten times!

Answer (score 1):

Had to enable google compute read/write access when setting up the VM

Comment: i'm facing the same problem, can you please explain the solution ?